# Фильтрация данных в Pandas на основе некой функции

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

встала необходимость в фильтрации датафрейма по некоторой функции. Например, у меня есть массив данных, состоящий из координат точек и другой, который состоит из координат вершин треугольника. На основе псевдоскалярного произведения, определяю, принадлежит ли точка из первого датафрема, треугольнику со второго.
Сейчас это все реализовано на двух циклах: первый перебирает точки, а второй треугольники. Хотелось бы сразу фильтровать второй датафрейм, чтоб получать из него только те треугольники, которым принадлежит точка. Существующее решение работает, но обработка данных занимает очень много времени.

Comment: В вопросе отсутствует собственная попытка решения, пример входных данных и ожидаемый результат, поэтому не совсем понятно что вы ожидаете получить в качестве ответа... Пока могу посоветовать обратить внимание на GeoPandas ...

Comment: не вижу кода, поэтому советую вслепую. В большинстве случаев полный перебор можно сократить путем простых проверок. Например, если для точки T 
с координатами  (X0, Y0) и треугольника с вершинами  (X1, Y1)  (X2, Y2)  (X3, Y3) оказывается, что  X0 > max(X1, X2, X3),  то считать ничего не надо.